# XML Parsing Error : AJAX Chat

Tags: ajax

I am just trying to plant AJAX Chat for my website users. I have successfully completed the installation process with database configuration. But when I am trying to brows the domain.com/ajaxchat/index.php its returning this error given below:

XML Parsing Error: junk after document element Location: http://futurenext.esy.es/inc/chat/ Line Number 2, Column 1:

I think that the problem is in AJAXChatTemplate.php , and here the code is:

```
function getContent() {
    if(!$this->_content) {
        $this->_content = AJAXChatFileSystem::getFileContents($this->_templateFile);
    }
    return $this->_content;
```

And the error message is like:

```
" Non-static method AJAXChatFileSystem::getFileContents() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in line 37"
```

Now please any one can help me to fix the problem. What is the problem here I can't really understand. Thanks.